# Ordenar um List em java que contém valores nulos

Tags: java, lista, arraylist, comparação, collection

Bom dia!

Na minha `List`, quando eu faço a ordenação eu gostaria que os valores nulos ficassem por último.

Vou mostrar um exemplo pra ficar mais claro:

Saída do código (nesse caso a palavra seria a letra depois do numero):

> ```
> SEM ORDENAÇÃO:
> 10c 2018-01-01
> 11b null
> 12a 2018-01-02
>
> ORDENADO PELO NÚMERO:  
> 10c 2018-01-01
> 11b null
> 12a 2018-01-02
>
> ORDENADO PELA PALAVRA: 
> 12a 2018-01-02 
> 11b null 
> 10c 2018-01-01
>
> ORDENADO PELA DATA: 
> 10c 2018-01-01 
> 11b null 
> 12a 2018-01-02
> ```

Vocês podem perceber que na ordenação pela data o valor nulo ficou antes de um valor não nulo, e eu gostaria que o valor nulo ficasse por último. Segue o fonte abaixo:

Classe main:

```java
public class Main 
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Objeto o1 = new Objeto();
        Objeto o2 = new Objeto();
        Objeto o3 = new Objeto();

        o1.numero = 1;
        o1.palavra = "c";
        o1.data = LocalDate.of(2018, 01, 1);

        o2.numero = 2;
        o2.palavra = "b";

        o3.numero = 3;
        o3.palavra = "a";
        o3.data = LocalDate.of(2018, 01, 2);

        List<Objeto> objetos = new ArrayList<>();
        objetos.add(o1);
        objetos.add(o2);
        objetos.add(o3);

        System.out.println("SEM ORDENAÇÃO:\n");
        for(Objeto objeto : objetos)
        {
            System.out.println(objeto.numero + '\t' + objeto.palavra + '\t' + objeto.data);
        }

        System.out.println("\n\nORDENADO PELO NÚMERO:");
        Collections.sort(objetos, new ObjetoComparator(1));
        for(Objeto objeto : objetos)
        {
            System.out.println(objeto.numero + '\t' + objeto.palavra + '\t' + objeto.data);
        }

        System.out.println("\n\nORDENADO PELa PALAVRA:");
        Collections.sort(objetos, new ObjetoComparator(2));
        for(Objeto objeto : objetos)
        {
            System.out.println(objeto.numero + '\t' + objeto.palavra + '\t' + objeto.data);
        }

        System.out.println("\n\nORDENADO PELA DATA::");
        Collections.sort(objetos, new ObjetoComparator(3));
        for(Objeto objeto : objetos)
        {
            System.out.println(objeto.numero + '\t' + objeto.palavra + '\t' + objeto.data);
        }
    }
}
```

Classe do Objeto:

```java
public class Objeto 
{
    public int numero;
    public String palavra;
    public LocalDate data;

}
```

Classe de comparação:

```java
public class ObjetoComparator implements Comparator<Objeto>
{
    /*
     * 1 - Compara pelo numero
     * 2 - Compara pela palavra
     * 3 - Compara pela data
     */
    private int ord;

    public ObjetoComparator(int Ord)
    {
        this.ord = Ord;
    }

    public int compare(Objeto o1, Objeto o2)
    {
        switch(this.ord)
        {
            case 1:
                if (o1.numero < o2.numero)
                    return -1;
                if (o1.numero > o2.numero)
                    return 1;

                return 0;

            case 2:
                return o1.palavra.compareTo(o2.palavra);

            case 3:
                try
                {
                    return o1.data.compareTo(o2.data);  
                }
                catch(NullPointerException e)
                {
                    return -1;
                }

            default:
                return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o método `nullsLast` da classe `Comparator`:

Classe `Objeto`:

```
public class Objeto {

    private int numero;

    private String palavra;

    private LocalDate data;

    public Objeto(int numero, String palavra, LocalDate data) {
        super();
        this.numero = numero;
        this.palavra = palavra;
        this.data = data;
    }

    public int getNumero() {
        return numero;
    }

    public String getPalavra() {
        return palavra;
    }

    public LocalDate getData() {
        return data;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Objeto [numero=" + numero + ", palavra=" + palavra + ", data=" + data + "]";
    }
}
```

Classe Realizando a comparação de datas:

```
Objeto o1 = new Objeto(1, "c", LocalDate.of(2018, 01, 1));
Objeto o2 = new Objeto(2, "b", null);
Objeto o3 = new Objeto(3, "a", LocalDate.of(2018, 01, 2));

List<Objeto> objetos = Stream.of(o1, o2, o3).collect(Collectors.toList());

objetos.sort(Comparator.comparing(Objeto::getData, Comparator.nullsLast(LocalDate::compareTo)));
objetos.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Excelente resposta. +1

Comment: Vlw mesmo, sua resposta está excelente. Muito completa.

Answer (score 4):

Primeiramente, nunca use atributos públicos. Isso é uma péssima prática de programação que deveria ter sido abolida e é condenada de forma quase que unânime por programadores experientes.

Além disso, é uma boa prática fazer esses objetos imutáveis se isso for possível (nem sempre é, mas se não for, que seja algo bem pensado nesse sentido), ainda mais quando se trata de um objeto cuja única responsabilidade é agrupar dados relacionados.

Eis a sua nova classe `Objeto`:

```
public final class Objeto {
    private final int numero;
    private final String palavra;
    private final LocalDate data;

    public Objeto(int numero, String palavra, LocalDate data) {
        this.numero = numero;
        this.palavra = palavra;
        this.data = data;
    }

    public int getNumero() {
        return numero;
    }

    public String getPalavra() {
        return palavra;
    }

    public LocalDate getData() {
        return data;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
         return numero + " " + palavra + " " + data;
    }
}
```

O seu `ObjetoComparator` tem três comportamentos diferentes (separados pelo `switch`). Neste caso, seria melhor criar três classes diferentes para não misturá-los:

```
public class ObjetoNumeroComparator implements Comparator<Objeto> {
    public ObjetoNumeroComparator() {
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(Objeto o1, Objeto o2) {
        return o1.getNumero() - o2.getNumero();
    }
}
```

```
public class ObjetoPalavraComparator implements Comparator<Objeto> {
    public ObjetoPalavraComparator() {
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(Objeto o1, Objeto o2) {
        String a = o1.getPalavra();
        String b = o2.getPalavra();
        return a == null && b == null ? 0
                : a == null ? 1
                : b == null ? -1
                : a.compareTo(b);
    }
}
```

```
public class ObjetoDataComparator implements Comparator<Objeto> {
    public ObjetoDataComparator() {
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(Objeto o1, Objeto o2) {
        LocalDate a = o1.getData();
        LocalDate b = o2.getData();
        return a == null && b == null ? 0
                : a == null ? 1
                : b == null ? -1
                : a.compareTo(b);
    }
}
```

Observe o método `compare` dos últimos dois casos. Eles verificam o `null` e o colocam no final. Isso é fundamental para que o programa funcione.

Com isso, ao invés de `new ObjetoComparator(1)`, você usa `new ObjetoNumeroComparator()`. Ao invés de `new ObjetoComparator(2)`, você usa `new ObjetoPalavraComparator()`. Ao invés de `new ObjetoComparator(3)`, você usa `new ObjetoDataComparator()`. Isso elimina a necessidade de ter-se um código numérico maluco e arbitrário para definir o comportamento desejado, separa esses comportamentos uns dos outros e possibilita que novos tipos de comportamentos possam ser criados sem a necessidade de alterar-se o código dos já existentes.

Seu código `Main` fica assim:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Objeto o1 = new Objeto(1, "c", LocalDate.of(2018, 01, 1));
        Objeto o2 = new Objeto(2, "b", null);
        Objeto o3 = new Objeto(3, "a", LocalDate.of(2018, 01, 2));

        List<Objeto> objetos = new ArrayList<>();
        objetos.add(o1);
        objetos.add(o2);
        objetos.add(o3);

        System.out.println("SEM ORDENAÇÃO: ");
        for (Objeto objeto : objetos) {
            System.out.println(objeto);
        }

        System.out.println("\n\nORDENADO PELO NÚMERO: ");
        Collections.sort(objetos, new ObjetoNumeroComparator());
        for (Objeto objeto : objetos) {
            System.out.println(objeto);
        }

        System.out.println("\n\nORDENADO PELA PALAVRA: ");
        Collections.sort(objetos, new ObjetoPalavraComparator());
        for (Objeto objeto : objetos) {
            System.out.println(objeto);
        }

        System.out.println("\n\nORDENADO PELA DATA: ");
        Collections.sort(objetos, new ObjetoDataComparator());
        for (Objeto objeto : objetos) {
            System.out.println(objeto);
        }
    }
}
```

[**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/tLlpyo). Eis a saída:

```
SEM ORDENAÇÃO: 
1 c 2018-01-01
2 b null
3 a 2018-01-02


ORDENADO PELO NÚMERO: 
1 c 2018-01-01
2 b null
3 a 2018-01-02


ORDENADO PELA PALAVRA: 
3 a 2018-01-02
2 b null
1 c 2018-01-01


ORDENADO PELA DATA: 
1 c 2018-01-01
3 a 2018-01-02
2 b null
```

Ah, também arrumei um bug, veja aqui:

```
System.out.println(objeto.numero + '\t' + objeto.palavra + '\t' + objeto.data);
```

O `\t` é interpretado como 9, então ele primeiro soma 9 ao `numero` e enconsta no resultado a `palavra`. É por isso que em sua saída aparece `10a`, `11b` e `12c` ao invés de `1 a`, `2 b` e `3 c`. Usando aspas duplas (`"`) ao invés de aspas simples (`'`), esse problema é resolvido.

Comment: Sim, quanto as boas práticas eu sempre as uso. Apenas fiz essas classes para exemplo, tanto que não tem utilidade nenhuma. O importante era a questão da ordenação mesmo.

Comment: A questão do nove eu não sabia, achei estranho não sair o tab no resultado. Obrigado por essa informação kkkk e enfim, muito obrigado pela resposta, ajudou muito : -)

Comment: Gostei das duas respostas. Mas tadinho do @CarlosRafaeldeOliveiraCarn :)

Comment: Mais uma pergunta. Maiúsculas e minúsculas interferem na ordenação de Strings?

Comment: @CarlosRafaeldeOliveiraCarn Sim, interferem. Você pode usar o [**método `compareToIgnoreCase(String)`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareToIgnoreCase-java.lang.String-) para resolver isso.